# Why unnatural isomorphisms are not mathematically well- behaved?

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

It’s said in nlab that

> Unnatural isomorphisms are not very well-behaved mathematically

Could you provide some examples illustrating this ?  Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: "Not well behaved" sounds like a strong claim to me. They do appear in a monoidal closed structure on Cat. I would rather say they are "not very interesting mathematically."

Comment: What is an unnatural morphism?